# How to share a temporary file with the Share Sheet?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a database, in this one I store small text notes.
I want to let the user select the notes that they want from a recyclerview (I already have this implemented) and if they press the share button, the app should create a temporary file just for sharing and that contains the note's text; if the user selected several files, it should make a .zip file with the corresponding .txt files inside of it.

Then, the share sheet shows up and lets the user send the file (txt or zip) to any file storage service or via email, for example.

How could I achieve this? Do I need to have the file already saved before sharing it or can I just create a reference to it without saving it and still be able to share it?

Comment: You can put those notes directly as text in an email.

Comment: `if the user selected several files, ` You said the user selected notes. And you wanted to make a file from the notes. You never told that the user could select files. A no complete story i would say.